# Tensorflow conv2d_transpose: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

When I build the FCN for segmentation, I want the images to keep the original size of input data, so I use the fully convolution layers. When I choose the fixed input size, such as (224, 224), the transpose conv works fine. However, when I changed the code of using (224, 224) to (h, w), I meet the following error. I googled before, but I didn't figure it out. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Error information:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: Size 
of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 62, computed = 
63spatial_dim: 2 input: 500 filter: 16 output: 62 stride: 8 dilation: 1
     [[Node: deconv_layer/conv2d_transpose_2 = 
Conv2DBackpropInput[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 8, 8], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"] 
(deconv_layer/conv2d_transpose_2-0-VecPermuteNHWCToNCHW- 
LayoutOptimizer/_1961, deconv_layer/deconv3/kernel/read, 
deconv_layer/Add_1)]]
     [[Node: losses/_2091 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, 
recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", 
send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", 
send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4480_losses", 
tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"] 
()]]
```

Code:

```
with tf.variable_scope("deconv_layer"):
    deconv_shape1 = block2.get_shape()
    W_t1 = deconv_utils.weight_variable([4, 4, deconv_shape1[3].value, 2048], 
                                        name="deconv1/kernel")
    b_t1 = deconv_utils.bias_variable([deconv_shape1[3].value], 
                                      name="deconv1/biases")
    deconv_t1 = deconv_utils.conv2d_transpose_strided(block4, W_t1, b_t1, 
                                       output_shape=tf.shape(block2))
    fuse1 = tf.add(deconv_t1, block2)
    print("deconv_t1: ", deconv_t1.shape)
    print("fuse_1: ", fuse1.shape)
    tf.identity(fuse1, name="fuse1")

    deconv_shape2 = block1.get_shape()
    W_t2 = deconv_utils.weight_variable([4, 4, deconv_shape2[3].value, 
                        deconv_shape1[3].value], name="deconv2/kernel")
    b_t2 = deconv_utils.bias_variable([deconv_shape2[3].value], 
                                      name="deconv2/biases")
    deconv_t2 = deconv_utils.conv2d_transpose_strided(fuse1, W_t2, b_t2, 
                        output_shape=tf.shape(block1))
    fuse2 = tf.add(deconv_t2, block1)
    print("deconv_t2: ", deconv_t2.shape)
    print("fuse2: ", fuse2.shape)
    tf.identity(fuse2, name="fuse2")

    shape = tf.shape(features)
    deconv_shape3 = tf.stack([shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], num_classes])
    W_t3 = deconv_utils.weight_variable([16, 16, num_classes, 
                       deconv_shape2[3].value], name="deconv3/kernel")
    b_t3 = deconv_utils.bias_variable([num_classes], name="deconv3/biases")
    deconv_t3 = deconv_utils.conv2d_transpose_strided(fuse2, W_t3, b_t3, 
                       output_shape=deconv_shape3, stride=8)
    print("deconv_t3: ", deconv_t3.shape)
```

The version with out custom functions is here:

```
    with tf.variable_scope("deconv_layer"):
    deconv1_shape = block2.get_shape()
    shape1 = [4, 4, deconv1_shape[3].value, 2048]
    deconv1_kernel = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.truncated_normal(shape1, 
                                 stddev=0.02),
                                 trainable=True,
                                 name="deconv1/kernel")
    deconv1 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=block4,
                                     filter=deconv1_kernel,
                                     # output_shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 
                             tf.shape(block2)[1], tf.shape(block2)[2], 512],
                                     output_shape=tf.shape(block2),
                                     strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                     padding='SAME',
                                     data_format='NHWC'
                                     )
    print('deconv1', deconv1.shape)
    fuse1 = tf.add(deconv1, block2)  # fuse1 = pool4 + deconv2(pool5)
    tf.identity(fuse1, name="fuse1")

    deconv2_shape = block1.get_shape()
    shape2 = [4, 4, deconv2_shape[3].value, deconv1_shape[3].value]
    deconv2_kernel = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.truncated_normal(shape2, 
                                 stddev=0.02),
                                 trainable=True,
                                 name="deconv2/kernel")
    deconv2 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=fuse1,
                                     filter=deconv2_kernel,
                                     output_shape=tf.shape(block1),
                                     strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                     padding='SAME',
                                     data_format='NHWC'
                                     )
    print('deconv2', deconv2.shape)
    fuse2 = tf.add(deconv2, block1)
    tf.identity(fuse2, name="fuse2")

    deconv3_shape = tf.stack([tf.shape(features)[0], tf.shape(features)[1], 
                              tf.shape(features)[2], num_classes])
    shape3 = [16, 16, num_classes, deconv2_shape[3].value]
    deconv_final_kernel = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.truncated_normal(shape3, stddev=0.02),
                                      trainable=True,
                                      name="deconv3/kernel")

    seg_logits = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=fuse2,
                                        filter=deconv_final_kernel,
                                        output_shape=deconv3_shape,
                                        strides=[1, 8, 8, 1],
                                        padding='SAME',
                                        data_format='NHWC')
```

Comment: I'll add my comment here instead of an answer. Make sure you're using the same arguments as training data generator for the test data generation. In my case, I had to make sure both input sizes and seeds matched.

Answer (score 2):

The conv Net and Deconv Net in FCN, which are built by different structures, are maybe not consistent with each other. In this case, the conv net use conv with `padding='VALID'`, while the deconv net uses all conv_transpose with `padding='SAME`. Thus the shapes are not the same, which causes the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your stride > 1. The calculation can not be correct at all time. This [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2118) post explains it.

Comment: Under my current knowledge, in FCN for segmentation, the up sampling is done by conv2d_transpose with "stride > 1". So I think what you mentioned may not be the key of the problem I met.

Comment: The error message you posted gives a Stride of `stride: 8`.  So you use a stride > 1.

Comment: I did use `stride > 1`. My opinion is that when you build the FCN for segmentation, it is necessary to use `conv2d_transpose` with `stride > 1` for up sampling. [This code](https://github.com/shekkizh/FCN.tensorflow) do use it that way. So I believe the error I met is not caused by `stride > 1`.

Comment: You don't have to use stride > 1 for upsampling. But you sample up more quickly, when you have a larger stride. Maybe they use sepcial cases, where you compute the output shape, but it is common knowledge that you can not

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while trying to replicate pytorch's transposeconv2d function in tensorflow. I was trying to do padding on input before passing to the conv2d_transpose() function and doing padding again on the deconvolved output. This was the reason why graph was initialized properly but there was error in calculating the gradients. I solved the error by removing all manual paddings and changing padding="SAME" inside the function. I guess this is handeled internally in the function. Correct me if I am wrong. I don't know how much this affects the actual output.